# Replace part of URL regardless of whether on staging or live

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have two versions of my Wordpress site - a staging environment and a live environement.

The staging environment URL has this format: **https://www.staging.example.com**

The live environment has this format: **https://example.com**

I need to change part of a url on my Wordpress site. Some lessons show up with the wrong url in search results, so I would like the links of these lesson related search results to redirect to the correct path to enable users to view the lessons, instead of reaching a 404 page.

I managed to figure out how to change part of the url via the .htaccess file doing the following:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^lessons/(.*) https://www.staging.example.com/method/course-name/lessons/$1 [R=301,L]
```

What I haven't figured out yet is how to change the url in such a way that it ignores the first part of the URL (https://www.staging.example.com or https://example.com). When I deploy from the staging site to the live site, I would like the .htaccess file to change the url's on https://example.com too (in the way I did in the code above - without having to go and manually change the domain in the .htaccess found on the live site).

I don't know what that would look like, but I imagine something like this, but this obviously doesn't work.

`RewriteRule ^lessons/(.*) ^example.com/method/course-name/lessons/$1 [R=301,L]`

Any ideas?

Comment: Just use a _relative_ URL (relative to the domain root) for the substitution part in your RewriteRule.

Comment: Thank you, that actually worked. Don't know why I didn't think of that!